# How to set executor memory in spark during Runtime

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop

I know how to set executor memory beforehand that while spark submit through `--executor-memory` and also to setup in config file using `spark.executor.memory`. But my question how to set executor memory while executing a spark-scala application during run time.

Comment: when you set the config of spark job and submit that job using spark-submit it will allocate memory at run time. for reference  https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#launching-applications-with-spark-submit

Answer (score 0):

Using the spark session getOrCreate like in this link => https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

Ex :

```
SparkSession.builder
  .master("...")
  .appName("Word Count")
  .config("spark.executor.memory", "2g")
.getOrCreate()
```

Comment: creating sparkSession is also not in my hands since, i have to use sparksession created by other team. i tried to set like below, but it didnt work.  spark.conf.set("spark.executor.memory","5g")